# Google Cloud auth access key secret key?

Tags: backupexec, public-key, keys, private-key, cloud-storage

Apologies for probably a basic question. Getting started with Google Cloud and require the access key and secret key to test online backups to Google Storage using Backup Exec 2015, however I can't find any clear instructions on how to obtain/create them. Tried the various authentications but can't see clearly where they are. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: Visit GCE console. Api Manager > Credentials.  here: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=[your-project-name]

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I was after finally found it in the storage interoperability, although the credentials still do not seem to show as associated with the bucket when accessing it via Backup Exec, or there is some rule blocking access to the storage bucket using the storage keys.

Answer (score 1):

@risyasin's comment is correct. In general, however, you should always start by reviewing the API documentation. For the cloud storage API, that information can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing).